# What is the best way to query only primary key in amazon dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have a dynamodb table with close to 5000 items. The primary key for this table is a column called "serialNumber". We have to run a scheduled job that picks up all the serial numbers and does some processing. What is the most optimized way to query for this data? We only need the serial numbers and not any other columns. Should I use scan/LSI/paginated query, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

instead of query all your data, i recommend to use dynamodb stream with lambda. you will be able to get only your primary key value, and do as ever you need.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to repeatedly get the list of all the serial numbers in the table you might do a scan with a projection of only the serial number. For a table with 5000 items this will execute really fast and won't consume a ton of capacity (you're probably looking at about 20 IOPs for the scan). For trivial loads and infrequent access (ie. once an hour, or once a day) a scan is the way to go - no need for excessive complexity.

However, if you expect that your table's contents will change all the time and you need near-real time updates then a Dynamo Stream to Lambda with potentially a cache would be the way to go.